# set fragment class at inflation time

Tags: android, android-fragments

i have about 60 fragments  "`ListFragment`" , now i use each Listfragment with another fragment in the same Layout file like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/carDetailedFragment"
            android:name="com.ui.fragment.CarDetailedFragment"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/carcategorylistfragment"
        android:name="com.ui.fragment.CarCategoryListFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the Question is :do i need to make 60 layout file for each fragment or  can i make a templete layout that contains 2 fragment and set their class

```
android:name
```

attribute at inflation time like setting attribute for the View ex

```
setContentView(R.layout.somelayout);
View v = findViewById(R.id.src);
v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Comment: Can you rephrase your question... it doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you can only do it in Java code.
In your XML, you'll have to have some sort of container for the Fragment. I believe that I just use a FrameLayout. Then you can do something like

```
YourFragment details = new YourFragment();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, details).commit();
```

EDIT: As a note. I don't believe that you really want to be newing up 60 fragments at once and keeping them and keeping them around in memory. The question you need to ask yourself is "Does this need it's own lifecycle?" If the answer is no then you can just create a custom View.

Answer (score 0):

I have a ton of layouts for ListView Activities and made it that I only need one ListView Fragment. [Use this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11122457/742030) - It will greatly reduce the amount of classes and redundant code needed.